# Drupal hierarchical menu theming

Tags: php, html, drupal-7

I've created a hierarchical main menu with drupal 7, looks like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16019885/Unbenannt.PNG

Now, i'm trying to fetch this menu via the following php code within my page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
    'links' => $main_menu, 
    'attributes' => array(
        'id' => 'menu'
    )
)); ?>
```

And i've added this function to my template.php http://drupal.org/node/855698#comment-4478948

But I still get just a normal menu.

Here is, what it looks like:
http://pastebin.com/ApukJY0w

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to setup the parent menu items as "Show as expanded".

To achieve this, in admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu/list, edit the parent menu item and check "Show as expanded".

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your answer. But it's still not working. Here is a screenshoot of the currently rendered HTML: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16019885/structure.png i guess it will not help you, but hope dies last.

Comment: In order to spot the problem, try to display the menu using a default Drupal theme like Bartik. If this works on Bartik, the problem comes form the theme you use. Some themes don't support nested menu or have settings to show children items. Alternatively, you can use the nice menu module which give great flexibilty.

Comment: I tried Bartik, still doesn't work. Then i deleted the PHP Code to fetch the navigation and placed the "main-menu" block inside my header, now it's working fine. :)